# Spark 2.3 with Java8 transform a row to columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark 2.4 with Java 8. I need help. Here is example of instances:

Source DataFrame

```
+--------------+
| key | Value  |
+--------------+
| A   | John   |
| B   | Nick   |
| A   | Mary   |
| B   | Kathy  |
| C   | Sabrina|
| B   | George |
+--------------+
```

Meta DataFrame

```
+-----+
| key |
+-----+
| A   |
| B   |
| C   |
| D   |
| E   |
| F   |
+-----+
```

I would like to transform it to the following: Column names from Meta Dataframe and Rows will be transformed based on Source Dataframe

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| A    | B      | C       | D     | E    | F    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| John | Nick   | Sabrina | null  | null | null |
| Mary | Kathy  | null    | null  | null | null |
| null | George | null    | null  | null | null |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Need to write a code Spark 2.3 with Java8. Appreciated your help.

Comment: Tell us what have you done so far.

Comment: I can get output if I use source table alone.  df1.groupby("key").pivot("key").agg(first("value").      Pls help me with use both data frame to get expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To make things clearer (and easily reproducible) let's define dataframes:

```scala
val df1 = Seq("A" -> "John", "B" -> "Nick", "A" -> "Mary", 
              "B" -> "Kathy", "C" -> "Sabrina", "B" -> "George")
          .toDF("key", "value")
val df2 = Seq("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F").toDF("key")
```

From what I see, you are trying to create one column by value in the `key` column of `df2`. These columns should contain all the values of the `value` column that are associated to the `key` naming the column. If we take an example, column `A`'s first value should be the value of the first occurrence of `A` (if it exists, null otherwise): `"John"`. Its second value should be the value of the second occurrence of A: `"Mary"`. There is no third value so the third value of the column should be `null`.

I detailed it to show that we need a notion of rank of the values for each key (windowing function), and group by that notion of rank. It would go as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val df1_win = df1
    .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
    .withColumn("rank", rank() over Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("id"))
// the id is just here to maintain the original order.

// getting the keys in df2. Add distinct if there are duplicates.
val keys = df2.collect.map(_.getAs[String](0)).sorted

// then it's just about pivoting
df1_win
    .groupBy("rank")
    .pivot("key", keys) 
    .agg(first('value))
    .orderBy("rank")
    //.drop("rank") // I keep here it for clarity
    .show()
+----+----+------+-------+----+----+----+                                       
|rank|   A|     B|      C|   D|   E|   F|
+----+----+------+-------+----+----+----+
|   1|John|  Nick|Sabrina|null|null|null|
|   2|Mary| Kathy|   null|null|null|null|
|   3|null|George|   null|null|null|null|
+----+----+------+-------+----+----+----+
```

Here is the very same code in Java

```java
Dataset<Row> df1_win = df1
    .withColumn("id", functions.monotonically_increasing_id())
    .withColumn("rank", functions.rank().over(Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("id")));
    // the id is just here to maintain the original order.

// getting the keys in df2. Add distinct if there are duplicates.
// Note that it is a list of objects, to match the (strange) signature of pivot
List<Object> keys = df2.collectAsList().stream()
    .map(x -> x.getString(0))
    .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

// then it's just about pivoting
df1_win
    .groupBy("rank")
    .pivot("key", keys)
    .agg(functions.first(functions.col("value")))
    .orderBy("rank")
    // .drop("rank") // I keep here it for clarity
    .show();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.      .pivot("key", keys)  doesnot working in Java8....if you provide it in Java8. it would be graet..df1_win
    .groupBy("rank")
    .pivot("key", keys) 
    .agg(first('value))
    .orderBy("rank")
    //.drop("rank") // I keep here it for clarity
    .show()

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. I am so used to coding in scala that I did not pay attention to the fact that you were asking about a java solution. I'll update my post ;)

Comment: I've added the code in Java. Did not test it though, let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its worked. Appreciated your timely help.

Comment: My pleasure, it's always interesting to come across original problems ;) If it's all good for you, can you accept the answer to close the topic?

Comment: One small doubt .. in dataframe, one column contains A1,A2,A3 as value and i want to convert to Rows as below                   Attribute column - Value  is A1,A2,A3 singel record. Want convert to three rows in the same dataframe   Attribute colume - Values are A1    A2  A3 - Three rows  - Java8 Spark 2.3  please help me

Comment: One doubt.. if i add one new column in source dataframe and same in meta dataframe..columnn name is "country" and value is IND for all rows. It is getting null after pivot. Please help me.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your questions. For the first one, it feels like `explode` could be a solution. For the second one, I think you could add that column in the group by. Yet it's hard to be sure without code, sample data and expected output. If this comment does not answer your concerns, I recommend you accept this answer for it answered your first question and ask a new question with all the details. (post the link here, I will have a look).