# Spark DataFrame: Ignore columns with empty IDs in groupBy

Tags: dataframe, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe e.g. with this structure:

```
ID | Date | P1_ID | P2_ID | P3_ID | P1_A | P1_B | P2_A | ...
============================================================
1  | 123  | 1     |       |       | A1   | B1   |      | ... <- only P1_x columns filled
1  | 123  | 2     |       |       | A2   | B2   |      | ... <- only P1_x filled
1  | 123  | 3     |       |       | A3   | B3   |      | ... <- only P1_x filled
1  | 123  |       | 1     |       |      |      | A4   | ... <- only P2_x filled
1  | 123  |       | 2     |       |      |      | A5   | ... <- only P2_x filled
1  | 123  |       |       | 1     |      |      |      | ... <- only P3_x filled
```

I need to combine the rows, that have the same ID, Date and Px_ID values, but without caring for empty values in the Px_ID when comparing the key columns.

In the end I need a dataframe like this:

```
ID | Date | P1_ID | P2_ID | P3_ID | P1_A | P1_B | P2_A | ...
============================================================
1  | 123  | 1     | 1     | 1     | A1   | B1   | A4   | ...
1  | 123  | 2     | 2     |       | A2   | B2   | A5   | ...
1  | 123  | 3     |       |       | A3   | B3   |      | ...
```

Is this possible and how? Thank you!

Comment: you can prefer this StackOverflow blog. this might be helpful for your problem "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108572/spark-2-3-with-java8-transform-a-row-to-columns"

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this problem: Since the non-relevant x_ID columns are empty, one possible way is to create a new column `combined_ID` that contains a concatenation of all x_ID column values (this will only contain one value, since only one x_ID is not empty in each row):

```
var xIdArray = Seq[Column]("P1_ID", "P2_ID", "P3_ID")
myDF = myDF.withColumn("combined_ID", concat(xIdArray : _*))
```

This changes the DF to following structure:

```
ID | Date | P1_ID | P2_ID | P3_ID | P1_A | P1_B | P2_A | ... | combined_ID 
===========================================================================
1  | 123  | 1     |       |       | A1   | B1   |      | ... | 1
1  | 123  | 2     |       |       | A2   | B2   |      | ... | 2
1  | 123  | 3     |       |       | A3   | B3   |      | ... | 3
1  | 123  |       | 1     |       |      |      | A4   | ... | 1
1  | 123  |       | 2     |       |      |      | A5   | ... | 2
1  | 123  |       |       | 1     |      |      |      | ... | 1
```

Now, I can simply group my DF by ID, Date and combined_ID and aggreate all the relevant columns by e.g. `max` function to get the values of the non-empty cells:

```
var groupByColumns : Seq[String] = Seq("ID", "Date", "x_ID")
var aggColumns : Seq[String] = Seq("P1_ID", "P2_ID", "P3_ID", "P1_A", "P1_B", "P2_A", ...)

myDF = myDF.groupBy(groupByColumns.head, groupByColumns.tail : _*).agg(aggColumns.head, aggColumns.tail : _*)
```

Result:

```
ID | Date | combined_ID | P1_ID | P2_ID | P3_ID | P1_A | P1_B | P2_A | ... 
===========================================================================
1  | 123  | 1           | 1     | 1     | 1     | A1   | B1   | A4   | ...
1  | 123  | 2           | 2     | 2     |       | A2   | B2   | A5   | ...
1  | 123  | 3           | 3     |       |       | A3   | B3   |      | ...
```